# How to change cpanel default port?

Tags: linux, apache, cpanel

I have one server and on that server cpanel is running on 2083 port. I need this url for configure my other service. I want to change port 2083 to 8088. Where i have to make changes. 
I checked my httpd.conf in that they wrote

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cpanel\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://127.0.0.1:2083/$1 [P]
```

So is there any change what i have to do in this file to change cpanel.

I checked cpanel/APACHE_CONFIG but i didnt get any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing port number in cpanel.config didn't work for me

So I used the internal port redirection i.e route all traffic on port 8088 internally to port 2083.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8088 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2083
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the file at /var/cpanel/cpanel.config

You can find this value:

`port=2082`

I believe this is the default cPanel port that can be changed.

Comment: to make 'that was work' do `/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/whostmgr2 --updatetweaksettings` and `/etc/init.d/httpd restart `

Answer (score 1):

```
You can change the cPanel port in /var/cpanel/cpanel.config file. Search for this line
--------------------
port=2082
----------------------
After changing the port, then run these two commands for it to take effect:

# /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/whostmgr2 --updatetweaksettings
# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

via : http://linuxworldweb.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-change-cpanel-port.html